# Pandas Reindexing MultiIndex Relative to Arbitrary Level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to reindex a dataframe relative to the second level of an index. I have a dataframe where the first level of the index is user id and the second level is date. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'id': 3*['A'] + 5*['B'] + 4*['C'],
'date': ['01-01-2010', '02-01-2010', '12-01-2010',
         '04-01-2015', '05-01-2015', '03-01-2016', '04-01-2016', '05-01-2016',
         '01-01-2015', '02-01-2015', '03-01-2015', '04-01-2015'],
'value': np.random.randint(10,100, 12)})\
.set_index(['id', 'date'])
```

I want to reindex the dates to fill in the missing dates, but only for the dates between the max and min dates for each "id" group.

For example user "A" should have continuous monthly data from January to December 2010 and user "B" should have continuous dates between April 2015 through May 2016. For simplicity let's assume I want to fill the NaNs with zeros.

Other questions similar to this assume that I want to use the same date_range for all users, which doesn't work in this use case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) + [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html) + [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': 3*['A'] + 5*['B'] + 4*['C'],
'date': ['01-01-2010', '02-01-2010', '12-01-2010',
         '04-01-2015', '05-01-2015', '03-01-2016', '04-01-2016', '05-01-2016',
         '01-01-2015', '02-01-2015', '03-01-2015', '04-01-2015'],
'value': np.random.randint(10,100, 12)})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(['id', 'date'])
print (df)
               value
id date             
A  2010-01-01     76
   2010-02-01     27
   2010-12-01     93
B  2015-04-01     67
   2015-05-01     96
   2016-03-01     57
   2016-04-01     83
   2016-05-01     42
C  2015-01-01     56
   2015-02-01     35
   2015-03-01     93
   2015-04-01     88
```

---

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level='id').groupby('id')['value'].resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)
print (df1.head(10))
               value
id date             
A  2010-01-01   76.0
   2010-01-02    0.0
   2010-01-03    0.0
   2010-01-04    0.0
   2010-01-05    0.0
   2010-01-06    0.0
   2010-01-07    0.0
   2010-01-08    0.0
   2010-01-09    0.0
   2010-01-10    0.0
```

But if need process only max and min `dates` first need select data with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html)
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax']).stack()]
print (df1)
   id       date  value
0   A 2010-01-01     76
2   A 2010-12-01     93
3   B 2015-04-01     67
7   B 2016-05-01     42
8   C 2015-01-01     56
11  C 2015-04-01     88

df1 = df1.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value'].resample('MS').asfreq().fillna(0)
print (df1.head(10))
```

Comment: This is close, but I don't need daily data. I need it monthly. Unfortunately, changing 'D' to 'M' doesn't work because it gives month end dates (which there is no data for so you just get all zeroes"

Comment: And if use `MS` instead `M` ?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you want?

```
In [52]: (df.reset_index().groupby('id')
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').mean().fillna(0))
    ...: )
Out[52]:
               value
id date
A  2010-01-01   91.0
   2010-01-02    0.0
   2010-01-03    0.0
   2010-01-04    0.0
   2010-01-05    0.0
   2010-01-06    0.0
   2010-01-07    0.0
   2010-01-08    0.0
   2010-01-09    0.0
   2010-01-10    0.0
...              ...
C  2015-03-23    0.0
   2015-03-24    0.0
   2015-03-25    0.0
   2015-03-26    0.0
   2015-03-27    0.0
   2015-03-28    0.0
   2015-03-29    0.0
   2015-03-30    0.0
   2015-03-31    0.0
   2015-04-01   11.0

[823 rows x 1 columns]
```

PS i have converted `date` to datetime dtype first...

Comment: Hi, I think this is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm not trying to downsample the data. I have monthly data and I need monthly data, I just need to fill in the missing months.

Comment: @Charles, does that mean that `'12-01-2010'` is `1 Dec. 2010`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

use `groupby` and `agg` to get `'start'` and `'end'` dates and build set up `tuple`s to `reindex` with.

```
m = dict(min='start', max='end')
df = df.reset_index().groupby('id').date.agg(['min', 'max']).rename(columns=m)
idx = [(i, d) for i, row in d2.iterrows() for d in pd.date_range(freq='MS', **row)]

df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

               value
id date             
A  2010-01-01     27
   2010-02-01     15
   2010-03-01      0
   2010-04-01      0
   2010-05-01      0
   2010-06-01      0
   2010-07-01      0
   2010-08-01      0
   2010-09-01      0
   2010-10-01      0
   2010-11-01      0
   2010-12-01     11
B  2015-04-01     10
   2015-05-01     94
   2015-06-01      0
   2015-07-01      0
   2015-08-01      0
   2015-09-01      0
   2015-10-01      0
   2015-11-01      0
   2015-12-01      0
   2016-01-01      0
   2016-02-01      0
   2016-03-01     42
   2016-04-01     15
   2016-05-01     71
C  2015-01-01     17
   2015-02-01     51
   2015-03-01     99
   2015-04-01     58
```